# Bulk lock users without email address?

Tags: users, bulk

I'm cleaning-up my database, and for the sake of keeping SPAM down to a minimum I would like lock all of the wordpress user accounts that do not contain an e-mail address.  Any ideas how to do this?

Please keep in mind that my level of PHP experience is "code tweaker" - most of the time I don't know what I'm doing but I'm able to personalize someone else's solution to my needs. My level of MYSQL is also pretty low - I can get around in there but I don't know how to make declarations that make things happen.

Comment: by lock do you mean you want to prevent them from logging in, or delete them from the database entirely? thase are two different solutions.

Comment: If you just want to deactivate the user accounts and not delete them, then please [take a look at this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/deactivate-user-accounts/).

Comment: I don't want to delete them from the database, just de-activate their account.  The plug-in ItsMePN linked to is helpful - though I have lots of users and I was hoping for a more automated way to find and group accounts without e-mail, and then de-activate them.  Thanks!

Comment: This can be done in the database. If you're using that plugin then it looks like you need to insert one row per deactivated user into wp_usermeta for each user with user_id pointing to them, meta_key='wpduact_status' and meta_value='inactive'. That should be easy enough to do in SQL if you can select the set of users you're interested in. I can't see how to create an account without an email address, though: what do your bad accounts look like? Is user_email in the wp_users table an empty string, or whitespace, or a null, or something else? Thanks!